# Exponential bound on the composition of linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dynamical-systems

Let $\varepsilon_n>0$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\varepsilon_n \to 0$. Let $A:E\to E$ be a continuous linear operator in a real Banach space $E$, and suppose that for every $x\in E$, 
$$
\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\frac{||A^{n}x||_{E}}{\varepsilon_n} <\infty,
$$
where $A^{n} = \underbrace{A\circ \ldots \circ A}_{n}$. Then, the sequence of continuous linear maps $\frac{1}{\varepsilon_n}A^{n}$ is bounded pointwise in $E$, and by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, there is a constant $C>0$ such that for all $n\geq 1$,
$$
||A^{n}||_{op}\leq C\varepsilon_n. \label{a}\tag{1}
$$
I should, however, prove something stronger: that there is $0\leq\lambda<1$ and a constant $K>0$ such that for all $n \geq 1$,
$$
||A^{n}||_{op} \leq K \lambda^{n}. \label{b}\tag{2}
$$
Since $(1)$ implies that there is $n_0 \geq 1$ such that $||A^{n_0}||_{op}<1$, it is possible to prove that $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists and is continuous, with $||(I-A)||_{op}\leq (1-||A^{n_0}||_{op})^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{n_0 - 1}||A^{i}||_{op}$ (for instance, [Corollary 2.3.3](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441904577-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-771016-p173898639) here has a proof). But I am still unable to show the exponential bound $(2)$.

Any suggestions or ideas would be helpful.

Comment: How are $A$ and $T$ related?

Comment: They are equal. I'm sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elementary approach using only $(1)$ and submultiplicativity should be this.

Eventually, $C\varepsilon_n\le\alpha<1$ for some (*any*, actually) $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Let $m_0$ be the first positive integer such that $C\varepsilon_n\le\alpha<1$ for all $n\ge m_0$. I claim $\lambda:=\sqrt[m_0]{\alpha}$ to be a good candidate.

In fact, since $\lVert A^{m_0}\rVert_{op}< \lambda^{m_0}$, for a generic $n\in\Bbb N$ it holds $$\lVert A^n\rVert_{op}=\lVert A^{qm_0+r}\rVert_{op}\le \lVert A^r\rVert_{op}\cdot\lVert A^{m_0}\rVert_{op}^q\le \lVert A^r\rVert_{op}\cdot \lambda^{qm_0}$$
where $0\le r<m_0$ is the remainder $\pmod{m_0}$ of $n$.

Thus, $K=\sup\{\lVert A^r\rVert_{op}\lambda^{-r}\,:\,0\le r<m_0\}$ does the job for the second constant.

Comment: That works! Thank you!